# Multiple responds to a XMPP iq-Stanza

Tags: xmpp

Is it possible to recieve multiple response to a XMPP iq-Stanza, so that in every response is the id, the id of the inital request. Or can you only recieve one response to one request?

Comment: The only reason I can thing of why one would want to split the response into multiple is if the responses caused by the request are available at different points in time. A comment XMPP pattern is then to deliver the additional responses in messages, which carry a shared identifier connected them together. I would consider a design where multiple IQ responses are returned an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[IQ Semantics](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-semantics-iq) doesn't specify it explicitly but it's a request-response mechanism, and if the response should be multi-value then `IQ` can contain multiple children.

Comment: Actually the standard explicitly specifies that an IQ can only have one child element, but nothing prevents that child element from carrying multiple elements with all your data.

Comment: @Flow that's what I meant, thanks for clarifying :-) (sort-a [brachylogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brachylogy) )